# How can I animate the background of a div when an element is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a website I'm making, I have some content that dynamically loads. What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the content loads, I would like the `div` to smoothly animate to expand to the size of the new content, sort of like the div does in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/363pknxy/) or this :

```css
.box {
    width: 200px; height: 100px;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 51%, black 49%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
    transition: background-position 1s;
}

.box:hover {
    background-position: 0 -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

That code uses a CSS transition as a hacky way to accomplish a slide.

```
transition: background-position 1s;
```

Instead, I would like to use JavaScript, maybe with JQuery, to get the `div` itself to resize to fit my content. For example, if the old content was longer than the new content, the `div` would slide to become smaller. If the old content was smaller, then the `div` would grow to fit the new content.

Currently, the `div` just jumps to be smaller, since the elements inside no longer need as much space. Is there any way to animate this content change? I have tried using CSS transitions but it was too complicated to coordinate the sizes of the `div` and content.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or a snippet of your code/example?

Comment: WHat do you have so far

Comment: may be something like this can help you http://jsfiddle.net/VVBra/

Comment: @JuanC. That's exactly what I had in mind! Thank you!

Comment: @JuanC. Why don't you write that as an answer?

Comment: didn't do it because i didn't write that, that's something that found on a quick search... but i'll add it

Comment: It's ok, it's still a solution...

Comment: That's fine because it solves the question, you can put the link to the original if you want. You can also make it yours if you, say, make it work with the CSS animations instead of the jQ animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get the original height of your container and the new height after its content has been updated

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VVBra/)**

```
function changeContent() {
    var oldHeight = div.height();
    texts.push(div.text());
    div.text(texts.shift());
    var newHeight = div.height();
    div.height(oldHeight);
    div.animate({height: newHeight}, 'fast', function() {
        div.height('auto');
    });
}
```

Comment: Note, you can also make this work using the CSS animations: http://jsfiddle.net/VVBra/81/